# Lucene: problems when keeping punctuation

Tags: lucene, full-text-search

I need Lucene to keep some punctuation marks when indexing my texts, so I'm now using a WhitespaceAnalyzer which doesn't remove the symbols.

If there is a sentence like `oranges, apples and bananas` in the text, I want the phrase query `"oranges, apples"` to be a match (not without the comma), and this is working fine.

However, I'd also want the simple query `oranges` to produce a hit, but it seems the indexed token contains the comma too (`oranges,`) so it won't be a match unless I write the comma in the query too, which is undesirable.

Is there any simple way to make this work the way I need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I'm bored and I'll reply anyway. I see two ways of doing this:

- Creating a `TokenFilter` that will create a synonym (e.g. insert a token into the stream with a 0 *position length*) each time a word contains punctuation with the non-puncuation version.
- Add another field with the same content but using a standard tokenizer that removes all punctuation. Both fields will be matched.